# Access a certain unknown field of a known class using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

Say I have the following class:

```
class Person
{
     public FirstType firstField ; // has a getter-setter  
     public SecondType secondField; // has a getter-setter  
     // more fields of other types
}
```

I want to build a function that accepts a `Person` class as its first parameter, and the **type** of one of the first parameter's fields as its second parameter - With the assumption that `Person`'s fields are of distinct types.

My aim is to be able to use reflection on the second parameter, and then use some equivalent of a dot notation to access the passed class.

```
public void SetPersonField(Person person, <should it be Type?> personFieldType)
{
   // accessing person's correct field type
}
```

How can it be done?

Comment: I hope that you understand that `firstField` and `secondField` are not **fields**, but actually are **nested types**. If your class looks this way, then it has **no own class members (fields, properties, methods) at all**.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I'll edit [EDIT to this post readers: before the correction, `firstField` and `secondField` were of enum types].

Comment: i can share my code with the following interface if it fits your need.`Public Shared Sub SetObjectProperty(ByRef obj As Object, propertyInfo As PropertyInfo, propertyValue As Object)` Yes, it is vb.net but it can be easily converted into C#. This code set any property(`propertyInfo` parameter) to `obj` object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be easily done with reflection: you can acquire all public properties of a type, find the one of given type, and sets its value in the context of passed `person` instance.

I would also recommend using generic method for slightly better type safety and more laconic usage:

```
public static void SetPersonField<T>(Person person, T value)
{
    typeof (Person)
        .GetProperties()
        .Single(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(T))
        .SetValue(person, value);
}

// Usage (both are correct):
SetPersonField(person, FirstType.EnumValue);
SetPersonField<FirstType>(person, FirstType.EnumValue);
```

You even don't need to specify generic type since it can be understood from input parameter.

Note that `.Single` will throw an exception if there are **no** property of this type, or if there is **more than one** property of this type. If either existence or uniqueness is not guaranteed, you need to handle it in your `SetPersonField` method.
Also, always keep in mind the huge performance drop when using reflection.

### What about being more generic?

You can implement a more generic method which will support **any types of properties and objects**:

```
public static void SetField<TObject, TProperty>(TObject obj, TProperty value)
{
    typeof(TObject)
        .GetProperties()
        .Single(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(TProperty))
        .SetValue(obj, value);
}

var person = new Person();
SetField(person, 123); // finds the only int property and sets its value
SetField(person, FirstType.EnumValue); // find the only FirstType property
SetField<Person, DateTime?>(person, DateTime.Now); // finds the only DateTime? property
```

Note that for some specific types (f.i., Nullable) you will need to explicitly specify types, since it cannot be understood from your data.

Comment: I am pretty It will fail for Enum types and for Nullable types

Comment: @Disappointed It works for enums, I've checked this before posting :) What about Nullable - there isn't a word about such requirements in the post.

Comment: yes, it is not mentioned. But as i understand author wants the code work for any possible types

Comment: As i understand (maybe i am wrong) there is still one major drawback in your code. Imagine during runtime user decides to change property "UserAge" to "20". How does your code can handle it ?

Comment: @Disappointed The idea described in the question is to make it possible to change a value of property by **type**, not name. If you know its name, then you can simply do `person.UserAge = 20`.

Answer (score 0):

I used this class some time ago

```
Public Class PropertySetter

Public Shared Sub SetObjectProperty(ByRef obj As Object, propertyInfo As PropertyInfo, propertyValue As Object)
    'if we do not need to convert propertyValue to certain type
    If IsNothing(propertyValue) OrElse propertyInfo.PropertyType = propertyValue.GetType() Then
        obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyInfo.Name).SetValue(obj, propertyValue)
    Else
        'Convert.ChangeType does not handle conversion to nullable types
        'if the property type is nullable, we need to get the underlying type of the property
        Dim targetType = If(IsNullableType(propertyInfo.PropertyType), Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyInfo.PropertyType), propertyInfo.PropertyType)

        'convert Enum
        If (propertyValue.GetType() = GetType(String)) Then
            If propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsEnum OrElse (Not Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyInfo.PropertyType) Is Nothing AndAlso Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyInfo.PropertyType).IsEnum) Then
                'if propertyValue is equal to enum value
                Try
                    propertyValue = [Enum].Parse(targetType, propertyValue.ToString())
                Catch ex As Exception
                    'if propertyValue is equal to enum description 
                    Dim enumValues = targetType.GetFields()
                    For Each enumValue In enumValues
                        Dim descriptionAttribute = enumValue.GetCustomAttribute(Of DescriptionAttribute)()
                        If Not descriptionAttribute Is Nothing Then
                            If (descriptionAttribute.Description.Trim().ToUpper() = propertyValue.ToString().ToUpper()) Then
                                propertyValue = enumValue.GetValue(Nothing)
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                End Try
            End If
        End If

        'set object property via reflection
        obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyInfo.Name).SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(propertyValue, targetType, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    End If
End Sub

Private Shared Function IsNullableType(type As Type) As Boolean
    Return type.IsGenericType AndAlso type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(GetType(Nullable(Of )))
End Function
End Class
```

P.S. As you see it's vb.net. You can use [this](http://converter.telerik.com) service to get C# code

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, here's how to make a Getter query:

```
public static object GetPersonField(Person person, Type fieldType)
{
    return typeof (Person)
            .GetProperties()
            .Single(p => p.PropertyType == fieldType)
            .GetValue(person);
}
```